# Prevent Mathematica from "romanizing" a string of letters?

Tags: front-end, stylesheet

When I'm authoring in text style (Alt-7), I'll often include inline math. Whenever I enter two or more consecutive letters (e.g., $ax^2$), Mathematica will automatically "romanize" (or "un-italicize") the letters (e.g., ax$^2$). Is there any built-in way to prevent Mathematica from doing this? (I'm sure there's probably a programmatic way, but I'm not experienced in that).
Thank you

Comment: Italicizing single letters is a special behavior (controlled by `SingleLetterItalics`).  Do you want everything in the inline cell italicized?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, not at all. For example, if I enter the general quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$, I don't want the exponent italicized, nor the plus signs, nor the equal sign, nor the 0. Basically, I'd want it the way it's conventionally typeset (like for example the way Latex does it!)

Comment: Alright.  I don't think I've seen that question before here, so +1.

Comment: If it proves impossible to control this with Style Sheets (resulting in automatic behavior) would it still be useful to you to have a script that would process a Notebook and set italic styling as described in all inline cells?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not quite sure what you mean. If you're asking me if I have a script, no I don't have any (I'm not experienced in Mathematica programming).

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo; I meant "useful to you **to** have a script..." -- would such a script be useful to you?

Comment: Sure, if the script could "re-italicize" a string of letters, that would be very useful to me (and others I suspect). Of course, the script would have to recognize exclusions such as "lim" "sin" etc.

Comment: The key point, it seems to me, is that the option is for *single letter* italics. So, rather than writing `ax`, you just write `a x` like you ordinarily would in *Mathematica*, except that you can use a very thin space (`\[VeryThinSpace]`) or a zero-width one (`\[InvisibleSpace]`). You can of course also italicize text explicitly, either using the keyboard shortcut or by editing the cell expression.

Comment: @OleksandrR. You're invisible space solution is creative, but it's an awful lot of extra typing and is ultimately a hack (no disrespect intended). I'd just as soon keep doing what I do now (explicitly italicize using Ctrl-I). It's surprising that a sophisticated program like Mathematica can't just typeset the math naturally the way Latex can. Perhaps I should contact Wolfram directly about this.

Comment: "Perhaps I should contact Wolfram directly about this." Sounds like a good idea to me, as that is the best way for things to change I suppose.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yeah I'll do that. I just thought I'd try the community first... Thanks.

Comment: @yroc I'm still hoping for a solution though I can't think of one myself (besides the script, assuming I could make it work).

Comment: It's not a lot of extra typing to use an invisible space.  Just type ESC space ESC.

Comment: @yroc it's not really a hack because that is the way *Mathematica* works anyway: `ax` is just not the same thing as `a x`. As Szabolcs says, the amount of extra typing is not really all that excessive.

Comment: @Szabolcs I wasn't aware of that shortcut; that's enough to make me switch to invisible space -- thanks!

Comment: @OleksandrR. I guess what I meant by hack is that you shouldn't have to insert an invisible space between variables to prevent Mathematica from Romanizing the variable string. If Latex is built to properly format math, why isn't Mathematica?). I realize that lack of a space in Mathematica does not imply times, but from a purely typographic standpoint, the italics should be retained IMHO (unless someone can give me a good reason otherwise). Maybe it's for the sake of translation from one expression form to another?

Comment: @yroc $\TeX$ assumes that individual characters typed consecutively without spaces are separate unless explicitly grouped, whereas *Mathematica* assumes they are grouped unless explicitly separated. Neither is wrong; they are just different. I don't agree that *Mathematica* "isn't built to properly format math", unless you consider any departure at all from what $\TeX$ does to be somehow improper. Maybe you want to try the `MultiLetterItalics` option, anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Enter an *invisible space* between `a` and `x` using the shortcut <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>is</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, or a *very thin space* using <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Invisible space:
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Very thin space:
[image: Mathematica graphics]